# Issue with hash_set : hash_set does not name a type

Tags: c++

In the following code

```
#include <hash_set>
using namespace std;
class sample
{
public:

    sample();
    ~sample();

    private :
    hash_set <unsigned int> a;
};
```

I get the following error - hash_Set does not name a type. Could you please point me to what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: hash_set is not a standard C++ type, probably it's in a diffferent namespace from what you are expecting

Answer (score 2):

The class you want to use is obsolete, use `std::unordered_set` instead.
As you can still include the header you could also try to use `stdext::hash_set`, though this is discouraged.

Comment: OK, Thank You. My compiler currently doesn't support unordered_set. Will change the compiler version